# Why is virtis a feminine noun, when it can mean "manliness"?

Tags: noun, gender

Keller's Learn to Read Latin says

> virtis, virtutis f. is an abstract noun formed by the addition of the suffix -tis to the stem of the noun vir.
> Its specific sense is thus "manliness" or “courage,” but it also may refer more generally to any intellectual or
> moral "excellence" or “virtue.”

Why is virtis a feminine noun, when it can mean "manliness"?

Comment: It's not *virtis* but *virtus*.

Answer (score 0):

For about the same reason German "Mädchen" is of the neuter gender. The endings of the noun in a gendered language (like the German diminutive ending "-chen") play a much greater role in determining the gender of a noun than the meaning does. Third-declension abstract nouns formed with the endings "-tus", "-tis" and "-tas" are predominantly feminine, so "vir-tis" is feminine. So is the Serbo-Croatian word "muževnost" meaning "manliness".